# NullReferenceException on ListBox(different page)

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, listbox, nullreferenceexception

So I'm facing this problem where I have 2 pages, ViewAccount and MainPage.

In MainPage there is a ListBox called SavedAccountsLst. The problem is that in the ViewAccount Page, once I click a button It throws a `NullReferenceException`.

This is the code I'm using in ViewAccount:

```
Private Sub Delete_Account_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim Storage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Storage.DeleteFile("SafeLockPLUS/SavedAccounts/" & PageTitle.Text)
    MessageBox.Show(PageTitle.Text & " has been deleted.", "Deleted", MessageBoxButton.OK)
    Dim aa = TryCast(DirectCast(Application.Current, App).RootFrame.Content, MainPage)
    aa.SavedAccountslst.ItemsSource = Nothing
    Dim directory As String = "./SafeLockPLUS/SavedAccounts/*.*"
    Dim filenames As String() = Storage.GetFileNames(directory)
    aa.SavedAccountslst.ItemsSource = filenames
    NavigationService.GoBack()

End Sub
```

What it's meant to do is that it will delete the file from the viewaccount page and clear the items in the SavedAccountList and reload them all in the ViewAccount page and then go back.

Comment: which line exactly throws the exception?

Comment: aa.SavedAccountslst.ItemsSource = Nothing

Comment: If you're in ViewAccount, then `App.RootFrame.Content` is `ViewAccount`, not `MainPage`, hence the error

Answer (score 0):

You execute this code when you are on `ViewAccountPage`, basically that means that `RootFrame.Content` contains a `ViewAccountPage` page, not a `MainPage`.

```
Dim aa = TryCast(DirectCast(Application.Current, App).RootFrame.Content, MainPage)
```

you are trying to cast `RootFrame.Content` to `MainPage` and your cast fails, so you get null in `aa` variable

Comment: I can't access the ViewAccount Because I'm already in ViewAccount and the only reason i added : Dim aa = TryCast(DirectCast(Application.Current, App).RootFrame.Content, MainPage) is to make a sort of reference so like from the ViewAccount Page i call the aa.SavedAccountslst.ItemsSource = Nothing, telling that from viewaccount page to clear the listbox called Savedaccountslst.

Comment: It that clear for you that there is no MainPage in RootFrame.Content?

Comment: You are accessing the RootFrame.Current, but do you understand that there is a ViewAccountPage in it?